# How to create HTML elements dynamically in a popup window?

Tags: javascript

Previously,I used the window.showModalDialog() function to popup a window:

```
window.showModalDialog("myHtml")
```

In myHtml,there are some html elements,like the textarea and two buttons.
But now the situation changed,any html file is not allowed.So I have to create the html elements dynamically in the popup window.Is it possible?

Comment: where is this method defined (showModalDialog), are you using a library maybe ?

Comment: This is very basic JavaScript, I hardly believe you couldn't find any documentation on the subject. [For instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement)

Comment: Yeah,you are right,you make me feel ashamed,self thinking is needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following code works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function createPopup(){
var popup = open("", "Popup", "width=300,height=200");
var txtOk = popup.document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
var aOk = popup.document.createElement("a");
aOk.innerHTML = "Click here";

popup.document.body.appendChild(txtOk);
popup.document.body.appendChild(aOk);
}
</script>
```

To call, use:

```
<div id="divPopup" onclick="createPopup();">Create popup</div>
```

Comment: It creates a popup window and adds controls to its document dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,and it works for me too.I should have thought about it myself first.