# Is it possible to pop up a html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime

My requirement is like I have a textarea which is disabled. On click of a button the user should be prompted for a datetime and it should be appended to the textarea value with a newline so that I can read it later one by one. Because I need to store these datetime values in an xml file which would be used to remember these values.

I am looking for a way to get a datetime input on click of a button. I thought to popup a datetime element to get the input using jquery. But I am not sure will it work or not. Is there any way to do it ?

```
<textarea id="schedule" name="schedule" placeholder="Mailing Schedule's" class="inputarea" disabled="disabled"></textarea>

    $('#addschedule').click(function(){
        var schedule=prompt("Enter Schedule");
        var val = $("textarea#schedule").val();
        if(val!="")
            $("textarea#schedule").val(val+"\n"+schedule);
        else
            $("textarea#schedule").val(schedule);
    });
```

I tried it for text input. But I dont know how to do it for datetime. Sorry If its not that good question. But some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes...completely possible. show us your attempt.

Comment: I updated the question. please check it out.

Comment: Why don't you create another DOM and show it as popup on click of button.

Comment: Check this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836838/how-to-create-html-elements-dynamically-in-a-popup-window

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    var mL = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    var mS = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var week = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var day = week[d.getDay()];
    var date = d.getDate();
    var month = mL[d.getMonth()];
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var total = day+' '+date+' '+month+' '+year+' '+t+'\n';
        var schedule=prompt("Enter Schedule", 'here');
        var val = $("textarea#schedule").val();
        if(val!=="")
            $("textarea#schedule").val(val+'\n'+total+' '+schedule);
        else
            $("textarea#schedule").val(total+' '+schedule);
});
    });
```

Comment: Hi It adds the current date and time.